# Plotting percentages for only one variant of a variable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, filtering, percentage

I've got data containing counts of participant Shape responses (either Angular or Round) grouped by a Manner variable with variants of Plosive, Fricative, Liquid and Nasal.

[This is my data table with counts converted to percentages for each Shape type, grouped by the different variants of Manner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbsVK.png)

(Code I used to create the table:)

```
manner_shape %>%
  group_by(Manner, Shape) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate (percentage = count*100 / sum (count))
```

I plotted the percentages into a bar chart.
[Bar chart for Angular/Round percentages grouped by Manner categories.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf3sM.png)

(Code I used to plot the percentages:)

```
manner_shape_plot <- ggplot(manner_shape, aes(Shape, group = Manner, fill = Manner)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=after_stat(prop)), stat="count", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(after_stat(prop)),
                y=after_stat(prop)), stat="count", vjust = -.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(~ Manner) +
    labs (title = "Shape selection for categories of Manner ", x = "Shape", y = "Relative frequencies")
manner_shape_plot
```

Now, I want to plot the percentages for only the Round Shape. In other words, I want the same graph as in the provided screenshot, but without the columns for Angular.

Help?

I tried using the filter() function to filter out the Angular responses, but that takes all of the Angular counts out of the equation and all of the Round counts are then 100%.

(The function I used:)

```
manner_shape_round <- manner_shape %>%
  filter(
    Shape == "Round"
  )
```

[After filtering out the Angular responses, all of the Round responses are now 100%.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG6O5.png)

[This is the resulting bar chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDwjI.png)

This is the data I'm using:

```
manner_shape <- structure(list(Consonant = c("z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", 
"l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", 
"r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", 
"l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", 
"r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", 
"l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", 
"r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", 
"l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", 
"r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", 
"l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", 
"r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", 
"l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", 
"r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", 
"l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", 
"r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", 
"l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", 
"r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", "l", "r", 
"l", "r", "l", "r", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t"), Manner = c("Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", "Liquid", 
"Liquid", "Liquid", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", "Nasal", 
"Nasal", "Nasal", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", "Fricative", 
"Fricative", "Fricative", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", 
"Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive", "Plosive"
), Shape = c("Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Round", 
"Round", "Angular", "Round", "Angular", "Angular", "Angular", 
"Angular", "Round", "Round", "Round", "Round")), row.names = c(NA, 
-784L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Consonant = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Manner = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Shape = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x7fb240ebc380>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try with filtering after computing the percentages. Otherwise there is only one group and hence the percentage is 100%.

Comment: Hiya, I tried adding the filter() function after the computations, i.e.,: dis_data_round <- dis_data %>%
  filter(
    Shape == "Round")
  And then wrote the plot using the new variable "dis_data_round", but the resulting bar chart still displayed 100% for all the Manner categories.

Comment: In that case: Perhaps you could provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data shared via `dput()`. Otherwise we can only guess what might be issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried using dput() to share my data. Please let me know if this is helpful. Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that while you computed the percentages you are actually not using the computed percentages for your plot but rely on `stat="count"` to compute the percentages. However, when you filter your data `stat="count"` can no longer take the second group into account and you end up with 100$ bars. To fix your issue I would suggest to compute your percentages outside of `ggplot2` and use the summarized data for your plot. Doing so you could `filter` your data for the desired group and will get the correct percentages.

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

manner_shape_sum <- manner_shape %>%
  group_by(Manner, Shape) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(percentage = count / sum(count))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Manner'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.

ggplot(manner_shape_sum, aes(Shape, percentage, group = Manner, fill = Manner)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(
    label = scales::percent(percentage),
  ), vjust = -.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(~Manner) +
  labs(title = "Shape selection for categories of Manner ", x = "Shape", y = "Relative frequencies")
```

[image]

```r
manner_shape_sum_filtered <- manner_shape_sum |>
  filter(Shape == "Round")

ggplot(manner_shape_sum_filtered, aes(Shape, percentage, group = Manner, fill = Manner)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(
    label = scales::percent(percentage),
  ), vjust = -.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(~Manner) +
  labs(title = "Shape selection for categories of Manner ", x = "Shape", y = "Relative frequencies")
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! You're a genius! I think you might have just saved my undergrad dissertation. Thank you so much.